# igraph creating a weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to use the `igraph` package to draw a (sparse) weighted graph. I currently have an adjacency matrix, but cannot get the `graph.adjacency` function to recognise the edge weights.

Consider the following random symmetric matrix:

```
m <- read.table(row.names=1, header=TRUE, text=
"           A          B          C          D           E         F
A 0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.05119703 1.3431599
B 0.00000000  0.0000000 -0.6088082  0.4016954  0.00000000 0.6132168
C 0.00000000 -0.6088082  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.63295415 0.0000000
D 0.00000000  0.4016954  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.29831267 0.0000000
E 0.05119703  0.0000000 -0.6329541 -0.2983127  0.00000000 0.1562458
F 1.34315990  0.6132168  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.15624584 0.0000000")
m <- as.matrix(m)
```

To plot, first I must get this adjacency matrix into the proper `igraph` format. This should be relatively simple with `graph.adjacency`. According to my reading of the documentation for [`graph.adjacency`](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.adjacency.html), I should do the following:

```
library(igraph)
ig <- graph.adjacency(m, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
```

However, it doesn't recognise the edge weights:

```
str(ig)
# IGRAPH UNW- 6 8 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] A--E A--F B--C B--D B--F C--E D--E E--F
plot(ig)
```

[image]

How do I get igraph to recognise the edge weights?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the problem, but do note that the matrix you've printed above is not symmetric. (Try `isSymmetric(m)`, and then compare, e.g., the values of `m[5,3]` and `m[3,5]`.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, it appears it's a simple copy&paste bug, numbers in columns A and E have 8 decimal places, while the rest has 7. Aside of that it's symmetric: `isSymmetric(round(m,6)) == TRUE`. Interestingly, `igraph` retained the version with the most decimal places, and in case of discrepancy added 0 at the end of the number with 7 decimal places.

Comment: The weights are there, `weight (e/n)` means that there is an edge attribute called `weight`, and it is numeric. See `?print.igraph`. But they are not plotted by default, you need to add them as `edge.label`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The weights are there, `weight (e/n)` means that there is an edge attribute called weight, and it is numeric. See `?print.igraph`. But they are not plotted by default, you need to add them as edge.label.

```
plot(ig, edge.label=round(E(ig)$weight, 3))
```

[image: graph plot screenshot]

For plotting, make sure you read `?igraph.plotting`.

Answer (score 13):

@TWL's solution can be easily generalized to represent edges' width as a function of the weights, including negative weights. The trick is to translate all weights by summing the value of the smallest weight (plus optionally an offset that represents the width of the minimum weight). For example:

```
# reproducible example:
set.seed(12345)
a <- matrix(runif(5*5, min=-10, max=10), ncol=5)
diag(a) <- 0 # remove loops.
>a
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000 -6.6725643 -9.309291 -0.7501069 -0.9254385
[2,]  7.5154639  0.0000000 -6.952530 -2.2371204 -3.4649518
[3,]  5.2196466  0.1844867  0.000000 -1.9502972  9.3083065
[4,]  7.7224913  4.5541051 -9.977268  0.0000000  4.1496375
[5,] -0.8703808  9.7947388 -2.175933  9.0331751  0.0000000

# create igraph object.
g <- graph.adjacency(a, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)
plot(g)

# assign edge's width as a function of weights.
E(g)$width <- E(g)$weight + min(E(g)$weight) + 1 # offset=1
plot(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As much as I love igraph, I've found the qgraph package easier to plot weighted networks.

With the adjacency matrix you can also just use `qgraph()` from the qgraph library to plot it.  It will automatically color negative edges a shade of red and positive edges a shade of green.

```
install.packages('qgraph')
require(qgraph)
qgraph(m)
qgraph(m,edge.labels=TRUE)  #if you want the weights on the edges as well
```

qgraph is built on igraph, but just does everything for you.

Comment: FYI: you **can** have negative edges in igraph. Also, `qgraph` just calls `igraph` AFAIK.

Comment: I realize that qgraph calls igraph. Its just easier to plot weighted networks with it because it does everything for you in the background.

Comment: Sure, I agree that's useful. The -1 was because you implied that igraph cannot handle negative edges, which is misinformation.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the edge weights with `E(ig)$weight`, and assign them to the `edge.width` argument in the plotting function:

`plot(ig, edge.width=E(ig)$weight)`

See the `?igraph.plotting` [[link](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/plot.common.html)] for reference.

Also, please note that in this example, the weights will correspond to the **width** of the edges, hence they should be `>= 0`.

Comment: Edge weights can be negative, there is nothing wrong with that AFAIK.

Comment: @GaborCsardi, I did not imply that the edge weights cannot be negative. In the context of my answer, they should be positive to be visualised as the **edge width**. Hence, I found -1 vote a bit hasty. Nonetheless, I edited the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: I see, sorry, misunderstood.